# How do companies like UberMedia/Near locate the home addresses of people who were detected somewhere else?

Tags: privacy, mobile, geolocation

This [news article](https://www.news.com.au/national/victoria/politics/new-data-shows-suburbs-where-freedom-protesters-hail-from/news-story/0cd209be41f532a3a4f813a44ae02d49) (cited in this [other question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/260496/127837)) shows that the company UberMedia (now rebranded [Near](https://near.com)) can retrieve the location of people's home from persons attending an event.

How does this company manage to get this information?

Comment: You could probably ask [this researcher](https://twitter.com/WolfieChristl/status/1282768887868723201) for any further question.

Answer (score 1):

From this [news article](https://www.foxbusiness.com/features/how-mobile-location-data-is-ushering-in-the-next-era-of-brick-and-mortar-business):

> According to UberMedia, the company collects 1.2 billion location data points per day coming from mobile app-based ad tracking data on smartphones, and uses that behavioral location data to help retailers in different ways.

We learn that UberMedia/Near's business is to sell ads on mobile phones. It uses [various](https://blog.near.com/technology/the-how-and-why-of-id-unification/) [sources](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ec1OBAcWkAAYjfk?format=png) of [identifying information](https://twitter.com/WolfieChristl/status/1282768887868723201) and join them to be able to track its users' physical location. This data comes from mobile ad providers, which have their SDK bundled into apps to distribute and display inside apps, and also to collect identifying information to track the users. Because those SDKs are bundled into apps, they can use their permissions, for example, to access the user's location. From Near's website, it does not appear that Near sells ads itself. However, it uses PII bought from ad providers to track users, and sells this tracking information.

Side note: Near's website has a [web page](https://near.com/privacy-policy/) explaining how their website is GDPR compliant. It conveniently avoids mentioning the tracking data they collect outside their website.

Comment: You can see my problem with the other question. It's a question that, once asked, suggests its own answer. The company explains the process.

Comment: @schroeder I see a 404 when accessing the other question. Maybe I'll be able to read it again once I'm back over 10K.